# Algorithm for adding two integers based on the use of standard logical operations like AND, OR, XOR, NOT

Tags: python, algorithm

**Algorithm for adding two integers based on the use of standard logical operations like AND, OR, XOR, NOT**

Does anyone know an algorithm for this?

I can't seem to find one that works as I am very new to Python.

I just need to it to help me in the right direction to make my binary addition program.

Comment: Half-adder or full-adder?

Comment: are you in the same class as this person? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026309/a-pseudocode-algorithm-for-integer-addition-based-on-binary-operation

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, this is actually a pretty standard thing to do [in hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)). I'll give a summary of the logic behind it here.

If you do this bit-by-bit, you can just use XOR and AND on the bits. Consider adding 13 and 6.

```
13 = binary 1101
6 = binary 0110
```

We now operate on the bits one at a time, right to left:

```
1 xor 0 = 1, 1 and 0 = 0 (no carry). "Current" result: 1
0 xor 1 = 1, 1 and 0 = 0 (no carry). "Current" result: 11
1 xor 1 = 0, 1 and 1 = 1 (there *is* a carry "out") "Current" result: 011
There's a carry in, so this is 1 xor 1 xor 0, which is 0. The carry out is 1. Current result: 0011
Next, we need to add the carry-out. Thus, the final number is 10011 (19).
```

Wikipedia has the [complete truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder) for this. From the same article, the logic for the digit is `(A xor B) xor Cin` where `Cin` is the carry in.

The logic for the carry out is

```
((A xor B) and Cin) or (A and B)
```

You can see a diagram of the digital circuit that I'm describing [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Full-adder_logic_diagram.svg), using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Symbols) description of the symbols.

From a more mathematical perspective, binary natural numbers form an [Abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) under addition, and binary natural numbers form a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)). (In fact, the fields of decimal and binary natural numbers are [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism)).

What this means in a more tangible sense is that binary arithmetic works in a way that's analogous to decimal arithmetic. It's still associative and commutative, for example. Point being that adding two binary numbers is a lot like adding two decimal numbers. Consider, for comparison to above, adding 904 and 117. Again, we add right to left.

7 + 4 = 13. Thus, the result is 3 and the carry-out is 1.
0 + 1 = 1. There's also a carry-in, so the result is 2.
9 + 1 = 10. Thus, the resulting digit is 0 and the carry-out is 1.

Final result: 1021.

Note how similar that was to adding the binary numbers. I'd suggest trying to add a few binary numbers "by hand" just to get more of a feel for how it works - it's almost exactly like arithmetic on decimal numbers actually.

Here's C# code to perform these operations, I'm assuming this is homework so I'll leave it as an exercise to "translate" this into Python :). (Hopefully the syntax is familiar - it's very similar to Java).

```
private static string LeftPad(string array, int length)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < (length - array.Length); i++)
        {
            sb.Append(0);
        }

        sb.Append(array);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static int AddBits(int num1, int num2)
    {
        // Convert the numbers to binary (base-2) strings
        string num1Bits = Convert.ToString(num1, 2);
        string num2Bits = Convert.ToString(num2, 2);

        // Track the current carry-in/carry-out
        int carry = 0;

        // If the strings are of differing lengths, left-pad the shorter one with zeros
        string num1ToAdd = (num1Bits.Length >= num2Bits.Length ? num1Bits : LeftPad(num1Bits, num2Bits.Length));
        string num2ToAdd = (num2Bits.Length >= num1Bits.Length ? num2Bits : LeftPad(num2Bits, num1Bits.Length));
        List<int> resultingDigits = new List<int>();

        // Loop through the strings from right to left and perform the operation listed above
        for (int i = num1ToAdd.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // Digits we are currently operating on
            int A = int.Parse(num1ToAdd[i].ToString());
            int B = int.Parse(num2ToAdd[i].ToString());

            int result = (A ^ B) ^ carry;

            resultingDigits.Add(result);

            carry = ((A ^ B) & carry) | (A & B);
        }

        // If there's a carry, add that as well
        if (carry == 1)
            resultingDigits.Add(1);

        // Change the endianness
        resultingDigits.Reverse();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < resultingDigits.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(resultingDigits[i]);
        }

        // Convert the base-2 (binary) string to a regular int
        return Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString(), 2);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'new digit'? Is this a type of algorithm I can use as a Psedocode for my program to help me?

Comment: @Bob I should've said "resulting digit." For example, if you're adding 0 and 1, the resulting digit is 1 (with no carry-out). If you're adding 1 and 1, the resulting digit is 0 and the carry-out is 1.