# A pseudocode algorithm for integer addition based on binary operation

Tags: python, algorithm

I have tried for ages to come up with a solution but just can't get my head around it.

It needs to be based on two integers on the use of standard logical operations which have direct hardware implementation AND, OR, XOR, NOT

It's a guidance for me to help with my project I am going to start, if anyone can explain it please.

I want this in terms of Python

Comment: Are you in the same class as this person? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41024409/algorithm-for-adding-two-integers-based-on-the-use-of-standard-logical-operation

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> add = lambda x, y: x if y == 0 else add(x^y, (x&y) << 1)
>>> add(5, 6)
11
```

Comment: It says multiple statements found while compiling a single statement. Is there one you can explain in a different way? Like a Psedocode type of method in terms of logical operations. So basically how we add binary on paper as Humans, but applied to a program?

Comment: Try to do it yourself, then if you encounter a specific problem you can ask about it...

Answer (score 1):

The basic component is a [full adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Full_adder). It has 3 inputs (a bit from `a`, a bit from `b` and carry) and two outputs (a bit of sum and carry). Its functionality is

```
    out = a ^ b ^ carry
    carry = a & b | (carry & (a^b))
```

Initially carry is 0. Apply the statements above to each bit starting from the least significant one.